# AlignmentX and Y of a JComponent without a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, boxlayout

I've seen some people using the `setAlignmentX()` and `setAlignmentY()` methods without a BoxLayout (e.g. when using a BorderLayout and other kinds of layouts).

Is this correct or does it do something at all? I haven't found any documentation explaining the use of alignmentX and alignmentY in JComponents but I have always thought it only affects BoxLayouts.

Comment: Some Swing layout managers use the setAlignmentX method.  Some Swing layout managers use the setHorizontalAlignment method.  The same goes for the corresponding Y methods.  I use these methods so infrequently that I try one, and if that doesn't work, try the other.  Yes, it's confusing.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *Some Swing layout managers use the setHorizontalAlignment method* -  This method is NOT used by the layout manager. This is a method of certain Swing components. When a layout manager sets a components size different than the components preferred size, it will allow the component to determine how to paint itself in the space available.

Comment: *I have always thought it only affects BoxLayouts* - A layout manager can choose to respect this or not. I have also only used this with a BoxLayout. The value will simply be ignored if the layout manager does not support the property. So you will not get an error if you use it with a BorderLayout, but the code will indeed be confusing.

Comment: Thank you @camickr!! (and sorry for my late reply). That's the answer I was searching for. Then AlignmentX and AlignmentY are properties of every JComponent and layouts can choose whether to use them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @camickr stated in the comments, `alignmentX` and `alignmentY` are attributes of a `JComponent`, and a layout manager can choose to support/respect them or not.

From the native layout managers, only `BoxLayout` does support this attributes, so if you try to use them on other layouts (e.g. FlowLayout, BorderLayout...) it won't do anything.

Of course you could [create your custom layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html) and choose to respect these attributes or not.